# The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) Map<String,Double>, int

Tags: java

How to perform division or multiplication with map without using key and values.

In below example i am having Developer as map object and want to multiply with 10 and assign it to another map.

```
 private Map<String, Double> Developer;
```

Having setter, getter method for Developer

```
 Map<String, Double> EmployeeVal = company.getDep().getProject().get(0).getDeveloper()*100;
```

if i am decalaring EmployeeVal as Double its working fine, but i dont want to do that, i want to declare EmployeeVal as Map only.

Comment: You can't multiply a map by `10` or any number for that matter...

Comment: And you can't assign a number as a `Map` instance.

Comment: What do you expect when you multiply `Developer` by 10? Java does not work that way. Arithmetical operations are only defined for the primitive number types.

Comment: what are you expecting by multiplying a developer by 10?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem starts with wrong naming convention.

Your Developer object is not a "developer", but a collection of Doubles with keys as String (names I guess?).

Aside of fact that it is better (and standard) to do not make variables started with capital letter your Developer variable should be named like  developersMap.

Then:
Do you want to multiply all values for all developers by 10?

If yes, make a loop through all of them and multiply values like:

example 1:

```
    for (String devKey: developersMap.keySet()){            
        developersMap.put(devKey,developersMap.get(devKey) * 10.0D);
    }
```

example 2:

```
    for (Entry<String, Double> devEntry: developersMap.entrySet()){         
        devEntry.setValue(devEntry.getValue() *10.0D);          
    }
```

But, if you'd like to multiply value for only one developer you have to get his value from Map by key, then multiply and put it back into Map.

As example you have two developers "John" and "Jane". for whom you'd like to multiply value?

"John":

```
developersMap.put("John",developersMap.get("John") * 10.0D);
```